# Append (add to tail) of linked list function in C is printing incorrectly (does not print out last element appended)

Tags: c, linked-list, append

this is my first post so kindly point out to me if I make any mistakes with my post.

This is a c assignment that takes commands from a text file (such as Push, Head, Append, etc) and then performs the corresponding operation for linked lists. I have a header file, a c file that has my main class and a c file with linked list functions.

All my functions work correctly, that is my remove(), push(), printlist(), head() and tail(), except for my append (add to end of list) function.

This is my structure in header file:

```
typedef struct node 
{
    char data;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

This is my append function:

```
node_t * append(node_t ** headRef, char data)
{
    node_t * current = *headRef;
    node_t * newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    // special case for length 0
    if (current == NULL) {
        *headRef = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Locate the last node
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }   
}
```

My print method (if necessary):

```
void print_list(node_t * head)
{
    node_t * current = head;
    if(current->next == NULL)                       /* IF no elements in list, */
    {
        printf("-\n");                          /* Print empty hyphen and new line*/
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)               
        {
            if(current->next->next ==NULL)              /* Otherwise if there are is one element */
                printf("%c\n", current->data);          /* Print character and a new line (last character) */
            else if (current->next==NULL)               /* Otherwise if there are is more than one element */
                printf("%c-\n", current->data);         /* Print character and hyphen between characters) */
            else
                printf("%c-", current->data);
            current = current->next;                /* Move on to next element in list */
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly this is how my main looks:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        node_t * test_list = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));

        FILE * fp;                          
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        char line[20];
        int lngth;

        while(fgets(line, 20, fp)!=NULL)                /* Loop to read every command in each file */
        {
            line [ strcspn(line, "\n") ] = 0;               /* Removes all nextline characters from array */

            //Here, I just get conditionals for the statement in the testfile
            //............
            else if(strncasecmp(line, "Append",4) ==0)      /* Check if line matches instruction 'Append' regardless of casing */
            {
                if(strncmp(line, "Append",4) ==0)       /* Now check if the line matches with casing */
                {
                    char letter = line[7];          /* If yes extract the alphabetical character to append */
                    append(&test_list, letter);
                }
                else                        /* If line casing not correct, output to stderr */
                    fprintf (stderr, "Input not valid\n");  
            }   

            else if(strcmp(line, "PrintList") ==0)          /* Check if line matches instruction 'PrintList' */
                print_list(test_list);              /* If it does, print out the list */
            //more conditionals
            //.........
            else                            /* Triggers if line does not match any above instructions */
                fprintf (stderr, "Input not valid\n");      /* Outputs to stderr */
        }
        fclose(fp);
   }
```

It appears to see my first element in the linked list as a 0 (empty space will be printed with printf("%c",node->data) for unassigned character

Test Case Example:

```
Input:
    Append A
    PrintList

Outputs:
    (Blank line)
```

As stated before, all other functions work correct and when printing, looks like A-B-C if 3 elements of A B and C exist and empty hyphen (-) when list empty.

Test Case 2 Example:

```
Input:
    Append A
    Append B
    Append C

Outputs:
    -A-B
```

Please point out to me where my logic is flawed. I suspect it is with my head not initially being null, however setting it to null causes my other methods to work incorrectly, and does not help append either.

Some research also indicates that if i initially set head to "z' for example, the output of append for test case 1 will be z and for test case 2 will be z-a-b

My main question is why does my append function not work correctly in conjunction with my print function, as it does not simply append all my elements as it should.

I am compiling with gcc on ubuntu 64-bit system.

Comment: Rework your `print_list` loop to use `while (current != NULL) ` instead of `while (current->next != NULL) `.

Comment: `append()` should be fine as long as `malloc()` succeeds... but `print_list()` needs work.  Remember `current->next` is `NULL` *for the last node*, and `current->next->next` is `NULL` *for the second to last node*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to 500 - Internal Server Error and Dmitri.

It was a problem as simple as that. I only thought my print method was working because of the other functions, not seeing that I was actually working around that all this time and had an extra element in my list.

I fixed it by changing my print_list methods as follows:

```
void print_list(node_t * head)
{
    node_t * current = head;
    if(current == NULL)                     /* IF no elements in list, */
    {
        printf("-\n");                          /* Print empty hyphen and new line*/
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        while (current != NULL)                 
        {
            if (current->next==NULL)        
                printf("%c\n", current->data);
            else
                printf("%c-", current->data);
            current = current->next;                /* Move on to next element in list */
        }
    }
}
```

I also could then in turn initialize my head to null in main as:

```
node_t * test_list = NULL;
```

instead of as:

```
node_t * test_list = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t))
```

Since I wanted an empty list so that my boundaries can work correctly and that I print out the last element, since  the old loop current->next != NULL stops at NULL and does not print out my last element.